# How to index the faces of a Icosahedron?

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I'm writing a simulation that acts on a grid mapped across the surface of a sphere.  The grid itself is a subdivided [Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron)  (The level of subdivision isn't known beforehand however)

With a grid of squares, it's easy to find adjacent cells because they'll be plus or minus 1 along either the x or y axis.  But that isn't the case at all with these triangles, my mind is having a tough time visualizing a way to index the cells.

Is there any sort of coordinate system I could use for addressing the faces of the icosahedron, that at least makes it easy to get the 3 cells adjacent to any arbitrary cell in the icosahedron?

Comment: This mesh is very small, so would there be anything wrong with simply storing a lookup table of adjacent triangles for each triangle?

Comment: @cfh - It's small without subdivision, but as each triangle is divided into four triangles with each level of subdivision, the number of faces goes up at a rate of 20*4^n

Comment: Ok, I see now. So it seems that the underlying icosahedron is actually irrelevant to the problem, and you simply want a fast data structure for accessing the neighbors of a triangle?

Comment: @cfh - I suppose so!  The underlying shape seems like it should be important, but I might be wrong about that ultimately

Comment: What's your main consideration? Low memory usage, speed, simplicity?

Comment: @samgak - simplicity first, though speed is important as well.  Memory usage isn't a concern too much

Comment: If memory usage isn't an issue then you can just store adjacency information for each triangle. However it is possible to use a structure where the adjacency information is implicit (as it is with a grid) at the cost of more complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each side of the icosahedron, you can map the triangles to a grid, with each grid square divided in two, e.g. (hex numbering of the indices for formatting convenience):

```
 A
 +
 |\
 |0\
 +--+
 |\2|\
 |1\|3\
 +--+--+
 |\5|\7|\
 |4\|6\|8\
 +--+--+--+
 |\A|\C|\E|\
 |9\|B\|D\|F\
 +--+--+--+--+
B             C
```

For a side sub-divided n times, there are 4<sup>n</sup> triangles in the side, so you can create an array of that size for each side of the icosahedron to store any per-triangle data for your simulation.

A reference to a triangle can be stored as (side,row,column)

Row and column indices are 0-based. The column index is based on the number of triangles in the row (i.e. 2 per grid square).

If you have the side, row and column, you can calculate the index into the array for the side like this:

```
index = (row * row) + column
```

So you can store the data in a 2d array and access it like this:

```
value = data[side][(row * row) + column]
```

Adjacent triangles for a triangle with an even numbered column:

```
(side, row, column - 1)
(side, row, column + 1)
(side, row + 1, column + 1)
```

Adjacent triangles for a triangle with an odd numbered column:

```
(side, row, column - 1)
(side, row, column + 1)
(side, row - 1, column - 1)
```

This allows you to easily reference triangles in a subdivided triangle mesh without explicitly storing adjacency information.

The catch is when it comes to organizing this into an icosahedron. After computing the references to the adjacent triangles, you need to validate that the new reference is within the bounds of the side:

```
int rows = 1 << subdivision_count;
if(row >= rows)
{
    // compute (side, row, column) in adjacent side of icosahedron to B-C edge
}
else if(column < 0)
{
    // compute (side, row, column) in adjacent side of icosahedron to A-B edge
}
else if(column >= ((row * 2) + 1))
{
    // compute (side, row, column) in adjacent side of icosahedron to A-C edge
}
```

You'll have to store adjacency information for each side, and which type of edge it is (AB, BC, AC).

There will be 9 different possible mappings that you will have to figure out, one for each combination of edge type. For example, if the adjacent triangle crosses the AC edge, and this edge matches the AB edge of the adjacent side, then

```
side = adjacent side (from table)
row = row
column = column - ((row * 2) + 1)
```

etc

It's a more complex approach in some ways but simpler in others. The advantages of all this are:

- no need to store adjacency information for individual triangles, only for the icosahedron sides
- 3D triangle co-ordinates can be computed for the triangle given a (side,row,column) reference if you store the 3D position of A, B, C for each side, so no need to store those per triangle either

Comment: for getting the adjacent side A-B, would it be `column < 0`?

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, you want to preprocess your geometry into a particular data structure which allows fast lookup of a triangle's neighbors.

If this is your only requirement, it is easy to "roll your own". For instance, for each triangle you would store its three edges, either as pointers to an edge structure or as indices into an edge table. Then, for each edge, you would store its two neighboring triangles (again either as pointers or as triangle indices).

This setup allows you to easily go from a triangle to each of its edges, and then to find from the edge structure the other neighboring triangle.

There are more advanced data structures for triangulated surfaces which allow more interesting operations to be done, for instance the [doubly connected edge list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) or the [winged edge data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_edge).

If you want to use a premade library, the [GTS library](http://gts.sourceforge.net/) will do what you need and much more.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question. The exact answer depends on exactly how you subdivide the faces of the icosahedron, which you don't say. But I'll give a framework for attacking the question.

First, let me say what I think makes the question easy in the case of a square grid: there is a mathematical group structure reflecting symmetry on the grid. To be precise, there is a pair of simple transformations (shift up; shift right) which together with their inverses generate every transformation of one grid cell to another. Furthermore, the shift up and shift right operations commute: the order in which you apply a sequence of operations doesn't change the outcome. The up and right operations generate the commutative group of transformations on the cell grid. The group is isomorphic to `ZxZ` so nice coordinates are given by pairs of integers `(m,n)`.

The lack of such a structure on the icosahedron is one of the problems for your question. There is a group structure on the icosahedron with two generators sometimes called "a" and "b", where "a" is a 180 degree rotation which maps a given edge onto itself, reversed, and b is a 120 degree rotation of a given face. The problem is that the group is not commutative, so ab != ba. That seriously complicates calculations with the group generators. Another issue is that this method triple covers each face (once for each rotation). There are 60 elements in the icosahedron rotational symmetry group A5, but only 20 faces on the icosahedron.

A very interesting way of addressing those issues was discovered by William Hamilton in the [Icosian calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian_calculus) and popularized in the [Icosian Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian_game). Remarkably, Hamilton gives generators for the icosahedron rotation group (which he symbolized by Greek iota and kappa instead of a and b) before the concepts of groups and generators were really invented (or at least well understood). Then Hamilton used his Icosian calculus to find a Hamiltonian circuit on the graph of vertices of the dodecahedron (or equivalently, the graph of faces of the icosahedron, since dodecahedron and icosahedron are dual to each other). See the graph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian_game).

That graph can be used to index the faces of the icosahedron in cyclic order from 0 to 19. Number the points in the graph of the vertices of the dodecahedron from 0 to 19 along a Hamiltonian cycle; that corresponds to a numbering of adjacent faces of the icosahedron also along a Hamiltonian cycle. Given a face m, two of its adjacent faces are m-1 modulo 20 and m+1 modulo 20; the third adjacent face is given by the dotted line in the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian_game). Maybe there's a nice formula or pattern for the index of the third adjacent face, but I don't see it offhand; it would be easy enough to store in a table.

If you subdivide the faces in a certain way, you can continue the Hamiltonian cycle into the faces. Subdivide each face into three faces by introducing a new point in the center of the face. Then you can find a Hamiltonian path through the three new triangles in a face (just go through them clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the relationship between entry edge and exit edge). If you further subdivide faces in this manner, you get a Hamiltonian path through the further subdivided triangles in the manner of a space-filling curve. The problem with that face subdivision is that the maximum of the edge lengths of triangles does not decrease.

For the more common way of subdividing triangles (by subdividing edges, instead of introducing new points at the centers of faces), I can't find a way of extending the Hamiltonian cycle on the icosahedron to a Hamiltonian path on the new figure. So it would probably be easier for you to use one of the other methods proposed for indexing triangular faces to find adjacent triangles within a face, and couple that with the method I propose for indexing faces of the icosahedron in order to find adjacent triangles in another face.

**Update**

I've been thinking about indexing the faces. Using images from the Wikipedia Page on [Triangular tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_tiling), a face will consist of a large triangular section of the infinite tiling

[image: Equilateral triangle tiling]

An affine transformation (which won't affect indexing) transforms that image to

[image: Right triangle tiling]

However, the latter image contains squares, so that the triangles are easily indexed by the x-coordinate of the bottom corner of a square, the y-coordinate of the bottom corner of the square, and a single bit (0 or 1) to indicate whether the triangle is yellow or green. The three triangles beside yellow triangle (m,n,0) are (m-1,n,1), (m,n-1,1), and (m,n,1), and the three triangles beside green triangle (m,n,1) are (m,n,0), (m+1,n,0), and (m,n+1,0); all of those operations are fast decrements, increments, or bit flips. Doubling the number of triangles is accomplished by breaking the square at (m,n) up into four smaller squares with coordinates (2m+0,2n+0), (2m+1,2n+0), (2m+0,2n+1), and (2m+1,2n+1), so the yellow triangle at (m,n,0) is broken into yellow triangles at (2m,2n,0), (2m+1,2n,0), (2m,2n+1,0), and a green triangle at (2m,2n,1), and the green triangle at (m,n,1) is broken into green triangles at (2m+1,2n,1), (2m,2n+1,1), (2m+1,2n+1,1) and a yellow triangle at (2m+1,2n+1,0); all those operations are fast shifts, adds without carries, and bit flips. Finally we can tell if a triangle (x,y,c) is out of bounds on the bottom if y coordinate goes negative, out of bounds on the left if x coordinate is negative, and out of bounds on a diagonal if x+y+c > whatever the size of the triangle is, another fast operation. No multiplies.

What do we mean by "bottom" for the faces of the three-dimensional figure? That is also answered by the Hamiltonian cycle: the "bottom" of any face is the side from which the (oriented) Hamiltonian cycle enters. That gives us an unambiguous orientation on each face.

So every sub-triangle now has a nice coordinate: (f,x,y,c) where f is the face of the icosohedron counted along the Hamiltonian cycle, x is the x-coordinate of the parallelogram containing the triangle, y is the y-coordinate of the parallelogram, and c is the color (0 (yellow) for bottom left, 1 (green) for top right). Neighbors can be calculated in three fast ops plus simple test for out of bounds, subdivision can be accomplished with just some shifts and adds without carries. If a neighbour test goes out of bounds you just decrement f mod 20, increment f mod 20, or lookup the "dotted line" face to the side. You can also iterate through every triangle in a simple manner, first iterating through faces, then through triangles with x+y+c = constant within each face.

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial to assign each triangle a tuple `{s,x,y}` where s denotes the side, and `x,y` denote the position within that side:

```
   /\ /Y
  /__\
 /\  /\
/__\/__\ ->X
```

This would have triangles {0,0}, {1,1} (middle), {2,0} and {0,2}. Within a plane, (same s) , the x&y coordinates tell you which triangles border. You'd need a single table for the 30 edges, which denotes per edge which triangles are on either side, and how their X,Y coordinates are ordered.

(You might be able to come up with a smart numbering instead of a table; I couldn't.)